# Azure Functions storage account: Used capacity is constantly rising

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-functions

I use a storage account to host 3 simple Azure Functions, which perform read, write and delete operations on a database. Surprisingly the *Used Capacity* value under *Metrics* is constantly increasing (please see screenshot below). Why? Those functions don't write anything to this storage. Since one pays for capacity used - am I going to pay more and more, if it continues to increase like that? I am a "Pay-as-you-go" customer by the way.

[image]

Edit#1: If I check the folder size of *File Shares* it says 2MB (see below). No clue where the values in *Metrics* are coming from...
[image]

Edit#2: Below are the *Application Settings*. Just the default values + Link to the MongoDB Atlas cluster. Could it be related to *AzureWebJobsStorage*?
[image]

Comment: Azure Functions provides metrics (application insights). You might have it enabled. As far as storage cost though: it's like... *2 cents* per GB per month.

Comment: can you share your application settings that you are using? You are probably logging which logs to the storage account in certain cases.

Comment: Application Insights are switched off for my functions. I agree that the price is negligible - still wanted to understand the reason. I added a screenshot of the Application Settings to the question. Thanks both for your comments!

Comment: @James answer below points in the right direction -- Functions uses the storage account for maintaining state, locks (via blobs), etc. The file share is also managed in your storage account as you see above. You should be able to look in your blob containers to see all of those details. Are you using any storage (blob/table/queue) triggers?

Comment: Hi @brettsam, no triggers used in my functions, just simple REST calls. But since posting the question the used storage has not increased any further. It actually decreased slightly. My impression is, that each time the functions are restarted a lot of data is stored. Anyway, thanks everybody for the support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every Azure Function requires a storage account.

[Storage account requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-app-portal#storage-account-requirements)

> When creating a function app in App Service, you must create or link
>   to a general-purpose Azure Storage account that supports Blob, Queue,
>   and Table storage. Internally, Functions uses Storage for operations
>   such as managing triggers and logging function executions.
>
> *Note*
>
> When using the Consumption hosting plan, your function code and
>   binding configuration files are stored in Azure File storage in the
>   main storage account. When you delete the main storage account, this
>   content is deleted and cannot be recovered.